# Dagger2 & Kotlin: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I trying to inject presenter using Dagger, but I get an error: lateinit property loginPresenter has not been initialized. I can't find what I may be doing wrong. See the code above from my classes. This is the first time I'm facing this problem.

LoginActvity.kt

```
package com.xsavzh.vkfriends.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpActivity
import com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.InjectPresenter
import com.arellomobile.mvp.presenter.PresenterType
import com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
import com.xsavzh.vkfriends.R
import com.xsavzh.vkfriends.presenters.LoginPresenter
import com.xsavzh.vkfriends.views.LoginView

class LoginActivity : MvpActivity(), LoginView {
    private lateinit var mTxtLoginHello: TextView
    private lateinit var mBtnEnter: Button
    private lateinit var mCpvWait: CircularProgressView

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var loginPresenter: LoginPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        mTxtLoginHello = findViewById(R.id.txt_login_hello)
        mBtnEnter = findViewById(R.id.btn_login_enter)
        mCpvWait = findViewById(R.id.cpv_login)

        mBtnEnter.setOnClickListener() {
            loginPresenter.login(false)
        }
    }

    override fun startLoading() {
        mBtnEnter.visibility = View.GONE
        mCpvWait.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun endLoading() {
        mBtnEnter.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mCpvWait.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun showError(textResource: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(textResource), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun openFriends() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, FriendsActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

LoginPresenter.Kt

```
package com.xsavzh.vkfriends.presenters

import android.os.Handler
import com.arellomobile.mvp.InjectViewState
import com.arellomobile.mvp.MvpPresenter
import com.xsavzh.vkfriends.R
import com.xsavzh.vkfriends.views.LoginView

@InjectViewState
class LoginPresenter: MvpPresenter<LoginView>() {
    fun login(isSuccess: Boolean,) {
        viewState.startLoading()
        Handler().postDelayed({
            viewState.endLoading()
            if (isSuccess) {
                viewState.openFriends()
            } else {
                viewState.showError(R.string.login_error_credentials)
            }
        }, 500)
    }
}
```

Logcat (Verbose):

```
2022-07-01 17:24:36.273 10590-10590/com.xsavzh.vkfriends E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xsavzh.vkfriends, PID: 10590
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property loginPresenter has not been initialized
        at com.xsavzh.vkfriends.activities.LoginActivity.getLoginPresenter(LoginActivity.kt:24)
        at com.xsavzh.vkfriends.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(LoginActivity.kt:35)
        at com.xsavzh.vkfriends.activities.LoginActivity.$r8$lambda$Uc8fB2ccpvnnJB-VVOCzsBXtCwM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.xsavzh.vkfriends.activities.LoginActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2022-07-01 17:24:36.315 10590-10590/com.xsavzh.vkfriends I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10590 SIG: 9
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xsavzh.vkfriends"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //MVP
    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-android:1.5.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.5'

    //Dagger
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.42'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.42'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.42'
}
```

Help me, please :)

Comment: I think you need to Inject LoginActivity in onCreate method.

Comment: Where is your DaggerAppComponent()/DaggerComponent? you're using dagger or hilt BTW?

Comment: Read the next discussion, maybe is the kapt plugin version https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/issues/41